# My Sim is utterly unlovable, how can I make him more likeable?

Tags: the-sims

I'm playing the original *The Sims* game, albiet the Complete Collection version.

I've created a family consisting of a single Sim, with the following traits:

- Neat: 10/10
- Outgoing: 4/10
- Active: 4/10
- Playful: 4/10
- Nice: 3/10

So far, I've gotten the knack of keeping my Sim alive... at least. However he is almost always unhappy because of a poor Social score. I discovered I can have him befriend and interact with the cats and dogs of the neighborhood which compensates for that, however he has no Sim friends to speak of, which is a problem because the next step in his career requires him to have a Family Friend.

Whenever I throw a party, or even simply interact with people, it always goes badly and his social score goes *down* and his relationships are damaged (what little relationship score I had I was able to build-up through phone calls).

I noticed that when interacting with others, my Sim only has the following options:

- Brag
- Flirt
- Tease
- Talk
- Invite Downtown
- Insult
- Say Goodbye

And whenever I choose any of these, it always goes badly and my sim's relationship with the other sim goes even lower, often negative.

The only thing I can do that improves relationships is talking on the phone once a day.

Is there anything else I can do, short of creating a new family with a higher Outgoing and Nice score?

Comment: This might be the most depressing Arcade post I've read to date=)  Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things you can try. 
If you have the complete version, which includes House Party and Vacation, then you should be ok.

Have a party and buy the bubble blower. This allows up to 4 people to interact with it. Have your sim and some others just sit there. Any social activity is fine: dance floor, campfire, etc...

For Vacation, playing the games that give out tickets with others around you allows them to talk to you.

If you want to, try playing with another family, then see if your Sim goes there for a visit. That way, they can interact with them without you worried about the stats.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also socialize when playing a game. Try having a party and play games or go to public areas (if your sims version allows this) so you play games with other persons.

For example you can play chess and it will have multiple bonuses.

- Train intelligence skill
- Have fun
- Social activity with other sims

Comment: Whenever OP try to simply talk to another Sim it doesn't go well, so I'm guessing that talking to others while doing those activities might also be dissatisfying for other Sims.

Comment: Well it is not certain because the other sim(s) are also having fun from the game. So there might be a slim chance.